# Make a string with 5 php variables

Tags: php, string, variables

Just think we need to echo a string something similar to this

```
sring01, sring02.<br />
sring03, sring04.</br />
sring05.
```

all string come from variables. It is not important to have true values for all five variable. if they have false or empty output string should be different from above. just assume we have 2 empty variable for string02 and string03, then output should be

```
sring01, sring04.</br />
sring05.
```

Can anybody tell me what is the best way to achieve this?

I just tried it something like this but it doesn't work for me if not all variables true.

```
if($addressOne||$addressTwo||$city||$province||$country) {
    $location  = "$addressOne, $addressTwo.<br />";
    $location .= "$city, $province.<br />";
    $location .= "$country";
} else {
    $location = "some text";
    }
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, do you mean it doesn't output the expected output, or doesn't output anything?

Comment: No it is working. but I can not get expecting result.

Comment: Can I have a solution without `HEREDOC`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1.place all variable in a single array variable as elemnets like this
2.Then filter array for false values using this array function
3. Then chunk the filtered array using

```
$array = array($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5); //place all variables in an array

$filtered = array_filter($array); //Filter all false values such as '', null, FALSE

$chunk = array_chunk($filtered, 2); //Chunk whole array to smaller groups with 
                                    //atmost 2 elements
$data = '';
   foreach($chunk as $value)
   {
      $data .= implode(',', $value) . '<br/>';  //Then join two elements with ',' symbol
   }
echo $data;
```

Comment: Can you tell me how can I get the output to the outside from the foreach loop?

Comment: Can you add comments for each line in your answer? It will help much for others to understand.

Answer (score 2):

first step:
Put all variables in an array and filter out the empty, false ones with the empty() function.

```
$values=array("value1", "", "value3", '',"value4", "", "value6", '');

$str ='';
$arrNew=array();
foreach($values as $v){
    if(! empty($v)) $arrNew []=$v;
}
```

second step:
iterate trough the new array and with the help of the modulo command set a line break, after each uneven loop counter number, except the number zero.

```
for( $i=0; $i<count($arrNew); $i++){
    if( ($i % 2 !== 0) && ($i !== 0) ) {
        $str .='.</br>';
    }else{
        $str .=',';
   }
}


echo $str;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<?php
$addressOne = "string1";
$addressTwo = "";
$city = "";
$province = "string4";
$country = "string5";

if(!empty($addressOne)) $string[] = $addressOne;
if(!empty($addressTwo)) $string[] = $addressTwo;
if(!empty($city))       $string[] = $city;
if(!empty($province))   $string[] = $province;
if(!empty($country))    $string[] = $country;

$str = "";
for($i=0; $i<count($string); $i++) {

    $str .= $string[$i];
    $str .= $i%2==0 ? "," : ".<br>"; 

}
$str = trim($str,",");
$str .= ".";

echo $str;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work, but it's not very nice. There are probably "nicer" solutions

```
$location = "";
$count = 0;

// The first string can be set if not empty
if($string01) {
  $location = $string01;
  $count++;
}

// second string 
if($string02) {

  // If $location is not empty we know the first was set and so we are have to add a "<br>"
  if($location != "") {
      $location .= "," . $string02 . "<br />";
      $count = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      $location = $string02;
      $count++;
    }
}

// For String 3 to 5 we have to check what our count is. when it is 0 then we don't have to add a <br> else we have because the string is the second in line
if($string03) {
  if($location != "") {
      if($count == 0) {
        $location .= $string03;
        $count++;
      }
      else
      {
        $location .= "," . $string03 . "<br />";
        $count = 0;      
      }
    }
    else
    {
      $location = $string03;
      $count++;
    }
}


if($string04) {
  if($location != "") {
      if($count == 0) {
        $location .= $string04;
        $count++;
      }
      else
      {
        $location .= "," . $string04 . "<br />";
        $count = 0;      
      }
    }
    else
    {
      $location = $string04;
      $count++;
    }
}

// For the last string we don't have to reset count because it's the last
if($string05) {
  if($location != "") {
      if($count == 0) {
        $location .= $string05;
      }
      else
      {
        $location .= "," . $string05 . "<br />";   
      }
    }
    else
    {
      $location = $string05;
    }
}

// Final text in $location
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$addressOne='ome';
$province='prov';
$country='$country';

if(!empty($addressOne)||!empty($addressTwo)||!empty($city)||!empty($province)||!empty($country)) {
    $locs = array();
    if (!empty($addressOne))$locs[]=$addressOne;
    if (!empty($addressTwo))$locs[]=$addressTwo;
    if (!empty($city))$locs[]=$city;
    if (!empty($province))$locs[]=$province;
    if (!empty($country))$locs[]=$country;
    $l = array();
    for ($i=0;$i<count($locs);$i+=2){
        $c=$locs[$i];
        if (!empty($locs[$i+1]))$c.=", {$locs[$i+1]}";
        $l[]=$c;
    }
    $location = implode('<br/>',$l);
}else{
    $location = "some text";
}
echo $location;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating separate variables for the respective positions and assigning the desired values to them, instead of trying to display the values from the original variables itself.

I am still a new-comer to PHP, so please point out any errors or mistakes `:)`

If suppose I consider the position variables as follows:

```
pos1, pos2.<br/>
pos3, pos4.<br/>
pos5.
```

then the following might work:

```
$pos = array ($addressOne, $addressTwo, $city, $province, $country);
for ($i=0; i<5; $i++)
  {
  if(!$pos[$i])
    {
    $j=$i;
    while($pos[$j+1])
      {
      $pos[$j] = $pos[$j+1];  //shift the strings one position to the front
      $j++;
      }
    }
  }
echo $pos[0].', '.$pos[1].'.<br/>'.
     $pos[2].', '.$pos[3].'.<br/>'.
     $pos[4].'.';
```

Please note that this wouldn't remove the `,` and `.` when the respective strings are absent. It is easy to do that though, and I thought it would be superfluous to include that in the answer.

Regards,
rktcool `:)`